# Classes or styles for a standalone index

Tags: packages, indexing, document-classes

I'd like to create a document which is a standalone index (of reviews: the data are the reviewer, the volume and page, and the name of the reviewed item).  Organising the data is not a problem (it is in a DB and I can script), rather it is making an attractive document which is the issue.

Any recommendations, in particular to classes or helpful styles?

[edit]

For example, a class to produce a document which looks like [this](http://printinghistoricalsociety.org.uk/publications/Index.pdf)

Comment: This is much too broad and opinion-based right now. Your 'attractive' might be my 'ugly'. What do you want it to look like? What format is the data file you want to input in?

Comment: @touhami, thanks for the response, but these seem to be packages/questions concerned with the _handling_ of the data; I'm rather interested in the _layout_ of pre-prepared data.

Comment: @crf. I would welcome subjective opinions of packages, I can then chose between them myself (and/or create a now package to my liking). The data are described in the question and are in a DB, not a file.

Comment: Note that I only get pinged if you get my name right. Anyway, the point is that questions which are likely to solicit subjective opinions are off-topic for this site. This doesn't mean they are bad questions: this just isn't the place for them. Questions here need to be such that it makes sense to ask whether one answer or another is the correct one, or more correct, or technically better (more efficient, more parsimonious, more transparent etc.). So to be on-topic, your question needs to be, basically, technical: how can I typeset *this*? Rather than, is this attractive?

Comment: I understand the data is in a database, but it will presumably be in a file when you feed it to TeX. What format will that file have?

Comment: Put it this way: if the format can be anything, you can have the format be, say, that of an `.idx` file (and transform it to `.ind` and include it in a `.tex` file. Or have it be `.ind` and include it in a `.tex` file. Then you can format it as you would a regular index. For example, as `.idx`: `\indexentry{<reviewer>, <item name>, <volume>}{<page>}`. This is more flexible as you can generate the `.ind` with an `.ist` of your choice.

Comment: @cfr, apologies for the misspelling -- the file fed to TeX is in any format which would be convenient to TeX, since I write the script which produces it. Something like a set of lines like`\item{...}\reviewer{...}\issue{...}\page{}` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point. On the first run, this produces an `.idx` file but, obviously, your script would do that. The file is just for the MWE.

So your script should produce a file `\jobname.idx` where `\jobname` will be the name of the `.tex` file without the extension e.g. if the file is `greatindex.tex` then your script will produce `\greatindex.idx`. (Best make a copy of this under another name, too.)

You then run `makeindex \jobname` e.g. `makeindex greatindex`. This produces `\jobname.ind`.

Then you can compile the `.tex` document which will input the file `\jobname.ind` and produce the index.

***Do not under any circumstances include `\makeindex` in your `.tex` file as it will overwrite your hand-written (effectively) `.idx`.***

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.idx}
\indexentry{reviewer1, aardvarks, I}{1}
\indexentry{reviewer2, jelly fish, II}{2}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{document}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: index]

The formatting of the index will depend on the document class you load and any packages you use to customise the formatting of section or chapter headings (as applicable) or, obviously, any customisation you enable for the index itself. (Default is a two-column index, I think. But I don't have enough entries to show this.)

If you want help with the formatting, create a proper Minimal Working Example and post a question explaining exactly how you want to modify the output.